# Consulta de base de datos php y mysql PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Alguien que me pueda ayudar.....
Quiero imprimir el id_usuario, segun yo ya en el html solo es un echo "$result"....

```
<?php 
session_start();

include "conexion.php";

$user = $_SESSION['usuario'];

$idusuario="SELECT id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = $user";

$id=$conexion->prepare($idusuario);

$id->execute();

$result = $id->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
?>
```

La conexion a la base de datos es por PDO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado con un `var_dump` o `print_r` a la variable `$result`?  Apostaría que es un array asociativo cuyo índice "id_usuario" almacena el valor que estás buscando.

Answer (score 1):

Si todo ha ido bien bien solo tines que recorrer los resultado por ejemplo con un `while`:

```
while($result = $id->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){ 
     print $result['id_usuario'].'<br>';
}
```

Si lo que quieres es optener el conjunto de resultados para recorrerlo mas tarde puedes utilizar `fetchAll()`:

```
$result = $id->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

// Luego lo recorres cuando quieres
foreach( $result as $datos ) {
    print $datos['id_usuario'].'<br>';
}
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que `$pdo->fetch()` devuelve la primera fila del conjunto de resultados y avanza el puntero. Mientras que `$pdo->fetchAll()` devuelve el conjunto completo de resultados.

Si solo esperas una fila deberías añadir un `LIMIT 1` a la consulta y también  puedes prescindir del `while`. Por otro lado deberías bindear con **`?`** los parámetros no tiene sentido utilizar sentencias preparadas y concatenar los parametros directamente en la consulta:

```
$idusuario="SELECT id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? LIMIT 1";
$id=$conexion->prepare( $idusuario );
$id->execute( array($user) );

$result = $id->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
print $result['id_usuario'].'<br>';
```